# Can't receive notification with Firebase in foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) to make notifications from my server to my IOS.
I only have one problem :
When my application is in the background, no problem, I receive a notification.
But when my application is in the foreground, My code print me the notification data but don't show it on the GUI :/

That's my function :

```
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void){
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey]{
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
}
```

Do you know how I can force Firebase to show the notification on the GUI ? I tryed to make a local notification instead, without results ...

Comment: This is not a problem ... it is normal behavior of iOS Notification ... when the app is in foreground, Notification UI do not show  at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to "Luca Rocchi", When the application is in foreground, the notification UI do not show at all.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device states :

If you want to receive notifications when your app is in the foreground, you need to add some message handling logic.

Implement AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: to handle notifications received when the client app is in the foreground, and all data messages that are sent to the client. The message is a dictionary of keys and values.

Granted I came here because I could not make it work either, but the doc DOES state that it's possible.